# Annotate scatter plot with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-plot, multi-index

I have constructed a scatter plot using data from a DataFrame with a multiindex. The indexes are country and year

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1)
rel_pib=welfare["rel_pib_pc"].loc[:,1960:2010].groupby("country").mean()
rel_lambda=welfare["Lambda"].loc[:,1960:2010].groupby("country").mean()
ax.scatter(rel_pib,rel_lambda)
ax.set_ylim(0,2)
ax.set_ylabel('Bienestar(Lambda)')
ax.set_xlabel('PIBPc')
ax.plot([0,1],'red', linewidth=1)
```

I would like to annotate each point with the country name (and if possible, the Lambda value). I have the following code

```
for i, txt in enumerate(welfare.index):
    plt.annotate(txt, (welfare["rel_pib_pc"].loc[:,1960:2010].groupby("country").mean()[i], welfare["Lambda"].loc[:,1960:2010].groupby("country").mean()[i]))
```

I am not sure how to indicate that i want the country names since all the `lambda` and `pib_pc` values for a given country are given as a single value, since I´m using the `.mean()` function.

I have tried using `.xs()` but all the combinations I tried won´t work.

Comment: Please provide a sample of *welfare* (for a couple of countries and years).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following test data:

```
               rel_pib_pc  Lambda
country  year                    
Country1 2007         260    1.12
         2008         265    1.13
         2009         268    1.10
Country2 2007         230    1.05
         2008         235    1.07
         2009         236    1.04
Country3 2007         200    1.02
         2008         203    1.07
         2009         208    1.05
```

Then, to generate a scatter plot, I used the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.scatter(rel_pib,rel_lambda)
ax.set_ylabel('Bienestar(Lambda)')
ax.set_xlabel('PIBPc')
ax.set_xlim(190,280)
annot_dy = 0.005
for i, txt in enumerate(rel_lambda.index):
    ax.annotate(txt, (rel_pib.loc[txt], rel_lambda.loc[txt] + annot_dy), ha='center')
plt.show()
```

and got the following result:

[image]

The trick to correctly generate annotations is:

- Enumerate the index of one of already generated *Series* objects,
  so that *txt* contains the country name.
- Take values from already generated *Series* objects (don't compute
  these values again).
- Locate both coordinates by the current index value.
- To put these annotations just above respective points, use:

  - *ha* (horizontal alignment) as *'center'*,
  - shift *y* coordinate a little up (if needed, experiment with othere
    values of *annot_dy*.

I added also *ax.set_xlim(190,280)* in order to keep annotations within the
picture rectangle. Maybe you will not need it.